# how to get rid of stopwords more effeciently using C++

Tags: c++

Now I have a stopword dict,and the wordlist need to be processed.How can I coding to imporve much effeciently?

My code is that:load dict into memory,using vectorstopword, and then iterator the wordlist,find if wordlist in stopword,if not in ,strcpy to newwordlist.

```
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{  
   stopword.find(a[i])=stopword.end());
   strcpy(new_word,a[i]);
}
```

But this code need to 2 loops?Can any other ways to imporve it?Using hash instead of vertor?

Comment: Use for stopword list unordered_map

Comment: what you mean using map.find is more quickly than vector.find?

Comment: unordered_map find is O(1).yes if your list big enough. So yes use hash

Comment: `strcpy` ? Use `std::string`, it will save you many headaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your stopwords in a structure called Trie. It is a prefix-based tree that will enable you to search for all stopwords at once, character-by-character.

See Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: ok,i will consider it later.But trie tree is much more complicatied to implemented.So I'd like to using map first